# How to send a character through telnet from Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I manage a running program by sending a command-character through telnet. I usually do it step by step:

```
telnet localhost 12345
command-character
ctrl+]
quit
```

Is it possible that I send the command-character from bash directly, or if not, write a bash script to do that?

Comment: `printf '%s' "$char" >/dev/tcp/localhost/12345`

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy My program prompted receiving a sigPipe signal. This seems to be raised by the underlying system.

Comment: Means you're writing to a closed FIFO.

Comment: Could this be caused by my program? It did respond to telnet service requests normally.

Comment: Whatever is on the other side of the FIFO you're writing to is the thing responsible for closing that end as-and-when it chooses to do so. If you need detailed control, btw, I would use `socat` instead of either `/dev/tcp` *or* `netcat`... but that should already be covered in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use telnet? I would use the netcat (`nc`)

Anyway the related thread:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160597

so for example:

```sh
echo 'c' | nc localhost 12345
```

for 'c' use any other character

Comment: Answers need to be complete enough to stand alone even if links they contain break. "I would use netcat" doesn't tell someone *how* to use netcat.

Comment: ok thank you, edited. That is why I have provided the link th the related thread.

Comment: Thank you @pstanko. With this command my program received the character, but it stays with the telnet session and didn't exit.